# What does robustness mean in the encoding context?

Tags: encoding, compression, aes, multimedia

I learn about the methods to encrypt multimedia files. One of them happens before the compression and it is the AES encoding of the pixel blocks. As an observation the article says that the disadvantage of this method is:

- the need of robustness against the encoder (alternatively communication  with the encoder so that the encoded areas will compress lossless)

I understand what the alternative in the parenthesis is but I can't figure it out what is the first method, the robustness is. Which are the methods / technologies to achieve this robustness?

Comment: This question really lacks context. Are you talking about **encrypting** video, for example for DRM? Instead of paraphrasing, perhaps _cite_ what you've read.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking about encrypting videos.